# Extracting first dimension of a tensor without using get_shape, size and shape functions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I wrote a loss function in Keras. It has two parameters, `y_true` and `y_pred`. My first line of code was: `batch = y_pred.get_shape()[0]`. Then in my `batch` variable I have first dimension of `y_pred`, so then I looped over `range(batch)` and wrote what I wrote. That doesn't matter. The matter is that when I compile everything, I got an error message that tells me that batch is not an integer, but a tensor. Then, as a beginner in Tensorflow, I started thinking how to get an integer from `batch`, which should be an integer, but a tensor. I tried to do `sess.run(batch)` but that didn't help at all. So, my problem is how to get an integer from a tensor that represents an integer variable. I would like to use some function which really gives me an integer, not tensor. Please help. Here is my code:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    batch = y_pred.get_shape()[0]

    list_ones = returnListOnes(batch)
    tensor_ones = tf.convert_to_tensor(list_ones)

    loss = 0
    for i in range(batch):
      for j in range(S):
        for k in range(S):
            lista = returnListOnesIndex(batch, [j,k,0])

            lista_bx = returnListOnesIndex(batch, [j,k,1])
            lista_by = returnListOnesIndex(batch, [j,k,2])
            lista_bw = returnListOnesIndex(batch, [j,k,3])
            lista_bh = returnListOnesIndex(batch, [j,k,4])

            lista_to_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(lista)

            lista_bx_to_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(lista_bx)
            lista_by_to_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(lista_by)
            lista_bw_to_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(lista_bw)
            lista_bh_to_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(lista_bh)

            element = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(lista_to_tensor,y_pred))
            element_true = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(lista_to_tensor, y_true))

            element_bx = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(lista_bx_to_tensor, y_pred))
            element_bx_true = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(lista_bx_to_tensor, y_true))

            element_by = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(lista_by_to_tensor, y_pred))
            element_by_true = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(lista_by_to_tensor, y_true))

            element_bw = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(lista_bw_to_tensor, y_pred))
            element_bw_true = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(lista_bw_to_tensor, y_true))

            element_bh = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(lista_bh_to_tensor, y_pred))
            element_bh_true = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(lista_bh_to_tensor, y_true))

            distance = tf.square(tf.subtract(element, element_true))
            distance_bx = tf.square(tf.subtract(element_bx, element_bx_true))
            distance_by = tf.square(tf.subtract(element_by, element_by_true))
            distance_bw = tf.square(tf.subtract(element_bw, element_bw_true))
            distance_bh = tf.square(tf.subtract(element_bh, element_bh_true))

            suma = tf.add(distance, distance_bx)
            suma = tf.add(suma, distance_by)
            suma = tf.add(suma, distance_bw)
            suma = tf.add(suma, distance_bh)



            loss += tf.cond(tf.greater(element_true,0.),
                            lambda: suma,
                            lambda: distance)
    return loss
```

As you see, I want `batch` variable to be `int` so that I could loop and do something. I also used `size` and `shape` and it wouldn't work also.

Comment: If the size of the first dimension is fixed you could do `batch = y_pred.get_shape()[0].value` to get its integer value, but being the batch dimension I imagine it is not fixed. You should compute the loss value in a vectorial way using TensorFlow constructs instead of Python loops, otherwise even if you fix the batch dimension it will most likely be very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectorized code will definitely be more efficient, and I would *strongly* encourage you to try to write the code in a manner which does not require looping.

However, if you are unable to do so, you can resort to [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn).

From your code I cannot see where `i` is used inside your loop. I'm guessing this is a bug (`batch` should be `i` inside the loop maybe) or my own blindness - otherwise you can just multiply the result by the batch size...

Comment: For example, returnListOnesIndex(batch, [j,k,2])  returns a list of the type [batch, 7,7,5] such that every [7,7,5] element inside of it has every zero, except at [j,k,2], which is 1. Then, when I convert it to a tensor and multiply it by y_pred, I'll get a tensor of all zeros except on the position [j,k,2], and that is y_pred[i, j,k,2]. It is really strange that I can't even see the first dimension of y_pred inside the function. It gives me that there is NonType. I can't see how.

Comment: If the first dimension has dynamic size (i.e. is unspecified and/or may change between batch runs) then this is expressed with a `None`. Also, it sounds like you want to be using `gather_nd`. I still don't see where the sub-batch index `i` gets used though, so at the moment you're just running the exact same thing `batch` times as far as I can tell.

Comment: I think gather_nd will help me. You are right about batch. I could write for _ in range(batch). The only problem is that I don't know what to write for batch if I can't write first dimension.

Comment: I just solved to problem. I used tf.where and tf.gather_nd. I would like to thank DomJack for help.